# Seeking polygon files corresponding to Russian Census?

Tags: polygon, data, census, russia

My team is using the [2010 Russian Census](http://www.gks.ru/free_doc/new_site/perepis2010/croc/perepis_itogi1612.htm) and we'd like to have polygons that correspond to these population values.  We're flexible to any sort of polygon format (shapefiles, GeoJSON, KML, etc). However we'd like low-level administrative boundaries, probably at the 'district' level.

We're currently using polygons from OSM, but would like to try polygons officially associated with the census (like the [TIGER](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html) files are associated with the US Census values).  I imagine these files exist somewhere internally within the Russian Census organization, so the staff can associate the right people with each administrative area.

Are these files publicly available?  If not, what is the best alternative, or where should we look?  Our team has a few native Russian speakers, so the material can be in Russian.

Answer (score 3):

You can download administrative shapefiles from [here](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata). Simply select *Russia* as your **Country** and *Administrative areas* as your **Subject**. You will receive 3 shapefiles of differing administrative levels so you can choose what level you would like. Here is are some attributes for the lowest level:

[image: Russia]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph, I don't think we had considered this source.  However, these files don't have an [OKATA](http://legalsystemltd.ru/en/sprav/okato.html) number that I recognize.  And we suspect these aren't a 1-to-1 match with the OKATO population data.  There are 5198 OKATO areas, and  RUS_adm2.df has only 2447 rows.

Comment: Ahh apologies, I did not know which classification type you were using. Hopefully others will advise on such sources.