# Map of russia's administrative divisions

Tags: shapefile, data, administrative-boundaries, postal-code, russia

I'm looking for a map of the administrative divisions of Russia, on a rather local level. In [Seeking polygon files corresponding to Russian Census?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/119564/115) is presented a map on different levels, the most local being just one level under the *oblast* level I guess :
[image]

I would like to know if it possible to find a more detailed administrative map, on the municipality level if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the Global Administrative Areas: http://gadm.org/?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I've checked on both [gadm.org](http://gadm.org) and [diva-gis.org](http://diva-gis.org) which give the same level of detail (as shown on the given map)

Comment: OSM might have Russian municipal boundaries: http://planet.openstreetmap.org/

Answer (score 4):

Try here: https://map.igismap.com/gis-data/russia; there are plenty of levels to choose from, the most detailed of them is called "administrative boundaries polygon".

Please note that you have to login to be able to download the file.